# YouTube Playlist Download

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I have a Youtube playlist, I want to download it but I want youtube-dl to name the files like 1-{video name}, 2-{video name}, ... n-{video name} in order to be able to watch them in the same sequence as original Youtube playlist. In other words I need my downloaded videos to be prefixed with numbers. How to do it?

Comment: Check [How to select video quality from youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486297/how-to-select-video-quality-from-youtube-dl) has more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [output template](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template):

```
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s.%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" PLAYLIST_URL
```

Replace `PLAYLIST_URL` with the URL of your playlist.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you need to install youtube-dl:

> sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl

2. Replace the existing youtube playlist url to your own:

> youtube-dl -cit https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC3y8-rFHvwg5gEu2KF4sbGvpUqMRSBSW

Answer (score -1):

You can check the detailed procedure and an automation code in the [my blog post](https://medium.com/@subash.cse66/robust-way-to-download-youtube-playlist-10-mins-command-f91b1f3d8d62)

Users face two main problems while using youtube-dl:

1. Outdated version. Make sure your version is >2016. You can use pip to upgrade, it itself will remove the outdated version and install newer version.

> `sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl`

To check youtube-dl version

> `youtube-dl --version`

2. Improper YouTube playlist URL

Eg:
The following link, doesn't work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoQkjWPpgyU&list=PLSQl0a2vh4HBf66MNFFBW1f76gFXFpr_U

Instead, we have to provide to provide https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSQl0a2vh4HBf66MNFFBW1f76gFXFpr_U